# Is there a way to automatically detect/monitor when new releases happen in Sidecar?

Tags: monitoring, versioning, sidecar, releases

I am running an application that relies heavily on Sidecar to get all the information from the node already decoded (as mentioned [here](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-node-interaction#substrate-api-sidecar)). So, it is quite critical for me to know as fast as possible when there is a new release in Sidecar since a possible omission of an update might disrupt the functionalities of my application.
Hence, I was wondering if there a way to automatically check / monitor whenever a new version of Sidecar is released.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some endpoints that might be useful:

- https://registry.npmjs.org/@substrate/api-sidecar (gives back JSON that contains all of the versions of the package that have been published; could be pulled periodically to check for updates).
- https://api.github.com/repos/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/releases (on github rather than npm, gives back JSON describing the releases of sidecar to date that it knows about).

npm is probably the better source of truth, since if you can spot a new release there, it's actually ready to download. Potentially, there could be a slight gap between a release being mentioned on Github and it being available for download on npm.

So if you are interested in monitoring, you could pull for example that npm endpoint and quite easily see whether a newer version has been released.